# React Material ui - centering item form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have my [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8ko4.png) but [i wanna do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sorko.png) i am working with react and material-ui.
What should i change so that my model looks like  in the second image?
i am using grid container and item. i must use grid o box?

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import PeopleAlt from '@material-ui/icons/PeopleAlt';
import CancelSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CancelSharp';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


export const Login = () => {

    return (

        <Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center" style={{ height: "200px" }} >

            <Grid item> <img src="/logo_ase.png" alt="image" /></Grid>

            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">

                <div>
                    <h6>Acceso al sistema</h6>
                    <TextField
                        label="usuario"
                        id="usuario"
                        InputProps={{
                            endAdornment: <InputAdornment> <PeopleAlt /> </InputAdornment>
                        }}
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <TextField
                        label="contraseña"
                        id="contraseña"
                        type="password"
                        InputProps={{
                            endAdornment: <InputAdornment> < CancelSharpIcon /> </InputAdornment>
                        }}
                    />
                </div>

                <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Ingresar     </Button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </Grid>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a div and put your left logo component and Login component inside that. Like this:

```
<div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
   <Left Component/>
   <LoginComponent />
</div>
```